# Start an AppleWatch Workout when GPS-tracking is started on iPhone

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

In order for the users of my fitness app to also get their Heart-rate recorded when they use our app on the iPhone, it would be nice to automatically start our AppleWatch App and retrieve the users Heart-rate from there. Is this somehow possible? I am pretty sure I found an API for that once but can't find it again any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everybody also searching

It was a method HKHealthStore: `startWatchAppWithWorkoutConfiguration:completion:`

See:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1648358-startwatchappwithworkoutconfigur